# Javascript loop create Object

Tags: javascript, object, each

i want to create an object but it doesn't work so far.

```js
 var optionz = [];
$('ul > li > a').each(function( index ) {
    optionz [ $(this).attr('href') ] = $(this).children('img').attr('src');
//  alert($(this).attr('href')+ " " +$(this).children('img').attr('src'));
});  
$.each(optionz, function (index, value) {
    alert( index + ' : ' + value );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="ul">
    <li><a href="gaga1.com"><img src="1.png"/></a></li>
    <li><a href="gaga2.com"><img src="1.png"/></a></li>
    <li><a href="gaga3.com"><img src="1.png"/></a></li>
    <li><a href="gaga4.com"><img src="1.png"/></a></li>
</ul>
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating an array, but you don't put items in the array. Instead you add properties to the array object. When you loop through the items in the array you won't find any, as there are none.

Create an object instead, when you loop through the object properties you will find the properties that you put in it:

```
var optionz = {};
```

Demo:

```js
 var optionz = {};
$('ul > li > a').each(function( index ) {
    optionz [ $(this).attr('href') ] = $(this).children('img').attr('src');
//  alert($(this).attr('href')+ " " +$(this).children('img').attr('src'));
});  
$.each(optionz, function (index, value) {
    alert( index + ' : ' + value );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="ul">
    <li><a href="gaga1.com"><img src="1.png"/></a></li>
    <li><a href="gaga2.com"><img src="1.png"/></a></li>
    <li><a href="gaga3.com"><img src="1.png"/></a></li>
    <li><a href="gaga4.com"><img src="1.png"/></a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

because you created key and value in an array is not really object, you should have created like this:

```
 var optionz = [];
 $('ul > li > a').each(function (index) {
     var obj = {};
     obj[$(this).attr('href')] = $(this).children('img').attr('src');
     optionz.push(obj);
 });

$.each(optionz, function (index, value) {
   console.log( index + ' : ' + value );
});
```

or you can change only this:

```
var optionz = {};
```